Error in terra::classify - Not compatible with requested type: [type=list; target=double]
I am trying to classify a spatRaster in a study area using terra::classify in three quantiles and I keep getting the message:

Error: Not compatible with requested type: [type=list; target=double].

You can find the raster in this link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VDcC_susw_8WaW2cOa-RvmoDwIOzyOHc/view?usp=sharing)
Does anyone has any idea why this is happening?
This is my code:
raster_het <- terra::rast("hetero_raster_sp1.tif")

# Example using quantiles
quantiles <- global(raster_het, quantile, probs=c(0.33, 0.66), na.rm=TRUE)

# Classify the raster into three categories

rcl_rast <- matrix(c(
  -Inf, quantiles[1], 1,         # "low" 
  quantiles[1], quantiles[2], 2, # "medium" 
  quantiles[2], Inf, 3           # "high" 
), ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)

hetero_class <- terra::classify(raster_het, rcl_rast, include.lowest=TRUE)



You need to pay attention to class of the quantiles and call their elements properly:
raster_het <- terra::rast("~/Downloads/hetero_raster_sp1.tif")

quantiles <- terra::global(raster_het, quantile, probs=c(0.33, 0.66), na.rm=TRUE)

quantiles is a data.frame, therefor either you have use $ to access its elements, either use double brackets, either call [row, col]
class(quantiles)
#> [1] "data.frame"

rcl_rast <- matrix(c(
  -Inf, quantiles[[1]], 1,           # "low" 
  quantiles[[1]], quantiles[[2]], 2, # "medium" 
  quantiles[[2]], Inf, 3             # "high" 
), ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)

hetero_class <- terra::classify(raster_het, rcl_rast, include.lowest=TRUE)
terra::plot(hetero_class)


Created on 2024-10-26 with reprex v2.1.0
